# TotalOrderPartitioner and Partition file

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-partitioning

I am learning hadoop mapreduce, and I am working with the Java API. I learnt about the TotalOrderPartitioner used to 'globally' sort the output by keys, across the cluster and that it needs a partition file (generated using InputSampler):

```
job.setPartitionerClass(TotalOrderPartitioner.class);
InputSampler.Sampler<Text, Text> sampler = new InputSampler.RandomSampler<Text, Text>(0.1, 200);
InputSampler.writePartitionFile(job, sampler);
```

I have a couple of doubts and I seek help from the community:

1. What does the word 'sorted globally' exactly mean here? How exactly is the output sorted, we still have multiple output part files that are distributed across the cluster?
2. What happens if we do not supply the partition file? Is there a default way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lets explain it with an example. Let's say your partition file looks like this:

```
H
T
V
```

This makes up for 4 ranges when your keys are ranging from A to Z:

```
1 [A,H)
2 [H,T)
3 [T,V)
4 [V,Z]
```

When a mapper now sends a record to the reducer the partitioner has a look at the key of your output. Let's say the outputs of all mappers are as follows:

```
A,N,C,K,Z,S,U
```

Now the partitioner checks your partition file and sends the records to the corresponing reducer. Let us assume you have defined 4 reducers, so each reducer will handle one range:

```
Reducer 1 handles A,C
Reducer 2 handles N,K,S
Reducer 3 handles U
Reducer 4 handles Z
```

This gives, that your partition file must hold at least `n-1` elements compared to the number of reducers you are using. Another important note from the [docs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/partition/TotalOrderPartitioner.html):

> If the keytype is BinaryComparable and
>   total.order.partitioner.natural.order is not false, a trie of the
>   first total.order.partitioner.max.trie.depth(2) + 1 bytes will be
>   built. Otherwise, keys will be located using a binary search of the
>   partition keyset using the RawComparator defined for this job. The
>   input file must be sorted with the same comparator and contain
>   JobContextImpl.getNumReduceTasks() - 1 keys.

Comment: Thanks! So 'globally' would mean that the zeroth reducer will be handling the first set of sorted keys, 1st reducer will get next set of sorted keys, and so on, I get. And how is the situation of no partition file handled, does a single reducer get all the keys? Or are the keys somehow evenly sorted and distributed by default among them?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you have to set a partition file. Another important note from the documentation: "If the keytype is BinaryComparable and total.order.partitioner.natural.order is not false, a trie of the first total.order.partitioner.max.trie.depth(2) + 1 bytes will be built. Otherwise, keys will be located using a binary search of the partition keyset using the RawComparator defined for this job. The input file must be sorted with the same comparator and contain JobContextImpl.getNumReduceTasks() - 1 keys."

Comment: If you want to only have one reducer simply set the number of reduce tasks to 1. Obvisouly no partitioning is necessary then.